# IIA problem on Quadratic Equations.

Tags: quadratics

How to show that expression $$\frac{px^{2}+3x-4}{p+3x-4x^2}$$ will be capable of all values when $x$ is real,provided that $p$ has any value between $1$ and $7$?

Regarding my personal attempts,they are all futile.

I tried to expand
$y=(px^{2}+3x-4)/(p+3x-4x^2$) to get a relation between $y$ and $p$ using "$b^{2}-4ac\geq0$"formula and substitute y with $1$.But,all futile.

Comment: will be capable ??

Comment: Do you mean the expression $\frac{px^2+3x-4}{p+3x-4x^2}$?

Comment: If $p$ is not between $1$ and $7$, then the expression is not capable of attaining the value $-1$.

Comment: @RoryDaulton,I mean the same.But being Ignorant of LaTex ,I am unable to edit.

Comment: @Arthur,How did you figure out that?

Comment: Set $\frac{px^2+3x-4}{p+3x-4x^2} = -1$, get $(p-4)x^2 + 6x + (p-4) = 0$. There is a solution to this equation iff $\sqrt{36 - 4(p-4)^2} = \sqrt{-4p^2 + 32p-28} = 2\sqrt{-p^2 + 8p - 7}$ exists. That square root exists when $-p^2 + 8p - 7$ is non-negative, which is exactly when $p$ is between $1$ and $7$ (inclusive).

Comment: @Arthur You should have given it as an answer.Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's not a full answer (there is no proof that you can reach _other_ values for the relevant $p$ values). Lab Bhattacharjee's answer below wants you to do the same, only not just for $-1$, but for all possible $y$ values at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Satrting from $$y=\frac{px^{2}+3x-4}{p+3x-4x^2}$$ rewrite the equation as a quadratic in $x$; this gives $$ (p+4 y)x^2-3  (y-1)x-(4+py)=0$$ Compute  the discriminant $$\Delta_x=(16 p+9) y^2+\left(4 p^2+46\right) y+16 p+9$$ Compute again the discriminant for this quadratic in $y$ $$\Delta_y=p^4-41 p^2-72 p+112$$ and this one must be negative or zero.

By inspection and succesive divisions, you could notice that this factors  $$\Delta_y=(p-7) (p-1) (p+4)^2$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Good job, man! (+1)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee. This coming from you, be sure I really appreciate !!

Comment: Could you please explain the third step?

Comment: If $\Delta_y \leq 0$, then $\Delta_x \geq 0$, I guess.